# Prestashop, problema instalando

Tags: prestashop

estoy intentando hacer una instalación de prestashop y me sale el siguiente error:
"Change the permissions of either "app/logs/" or "var/logs/" directory so that the web server can write into it."
La cosa es que la carpeta logs no existe dentro de la de app y la general "Var" tampoco existe.

Muchas gracias.

---

Quiero acalarar que la instalación se esta efectuando en una subcarpeta /web de la instalación principal, ya que mi cliente pretende renovar la imagen de la web.
Un saludo,

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad

Comment: Puedes probar a crear esas carpetas de forma manual y editar los permisos de lectura y escritura.

Comment: Algo tan simple y ni se me había ocurrido. Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ha funcionado.